# What is that "1 view" which automatically appears after submitting a question?

Tags: support, views

Are the questions submitted on SO and other SE sites initialized with 1 view, or does the first view belong to the user who posted it?

Why is a question given a free first view? It just appears, as soon as the question is published.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Are the questions submitted on SO and other SE sites, initialized with one view, or the first view belongs to the user who posted it?

Both. The 1 view you see is that of you, the question owner.

Why? Because you have viewed it.

Note that it isn't actually checking if you viewed it (I don't think). I just posted a question then closed the page 0.05 seconds later. So it is simply the software initialising with a new view, by default.

> Why is a question given a free first view? It just appears, as soon as the question is published. Why?

Well, views mean very little here. You can get a few badges for high view counts and... that's it.

So a "free view" - it means as much a free piece of paper. Umm, yay!?

Comment: You need to type 26 seconds faster :P

Answer (score 9):

You are a user, and as soon as you submit your question you are shown your new question = 1 view.

So the first view count is you :)