# How long do I have to be on a page for it to count as a "view"?

Tags: discussion, support, views

I have noticed that when I post a new question, it has a 1 view straight away.

It has this even if I post and then close the tab within 0.05 seconds. Is this long enough for the page to count a view?

Comment: Didn't you just answer the first part of your question for [someone else](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/259448/230506)? 0_o

Comment: @James yes, im using those experiments as an example... Maybe it doesn't fit, i'll remove it.

Comment: I can see why you're asking for clarification, but I doubt that the site system would invoke "1 view" as some auto thing for the sake of it. There would be nothing wrong with "0 views" if the site wanted to do that and not include the questioner as a view. I did presume a bit on my answer, but it seems pretty logical what is happening (imo). The site system just auto counts a view based on the question asker being a user and submitting. It might not even be the specific "view count script", but just the "question submit script" appending 1. Would be interesting to know though :)

Comment: I viewed one of my older questions recently. It had 2499 views. Can't remember the exact time, but from what I remember I received a notification very quickly that I just earned the Notable Question badge for 2500 views on a question. But that story of mine isn't much useful here when you're talking about milliseconds and such.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the code used to update the views count is not based on tracking pixels - those are only used by third party vendors as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 5):

You ask the question, therefore you count as a viewer of it anyway, because if the question is successfully submitted, you're redirected to it; if you close the tab while submitting, the redirecting turns in a somewhat invisible process to you (just btw there: the Chrome browser on Android has such a bug if I submit the question and then close the tab, the question will load submitted in my last tab, regardless of this tab's contents - this proves that the redirecting takes place anyway).

Therefore, how fast wouldn't you be, you'll never get zero views if your question is successfully submitted - you're counted as having visited it because system force you to actually visit it :)