# Using the views feature during searches

Tags: support, search, views

When I run `views:0` I come back with questions that have 100k or 300 views. Is the views feature greater or less than?

If I do `created:2021-09-09 views:0` I don't see anything that has 0 views or even 30 views.

I looked at the [search help](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/searching) and found this:

> - `views:500..1000` or `views:500-1000` will return posts with 500 to 1000 views

Are there no posts that have 0 views or less than 30 views? Do I need to catch the question fast enough to be able to see this? How does this work?

Comment: Why would you expect to see posts with zero views. The person who asks it is the immediate first viewer.

Comment: @Catija didn't know that. I Thought that the person creating the post just had a post and the system confuses the number so it starts a chain reaction of views so the question gets more attention. also, I don't browse the front page like that. I like typing in search strings then go looking for stuff to answer. I'm looking for any other suggestions you might have

Comment: @Catija Reddit makes numbers up or makes it confusing to the people on the sub so that there is no brigading or things like that. thought meta did the same thing

Comment: We have weird rules but the numbers aren't made up. Any view is counted and even multiple views by the same person count more than once - though there's a 15 minute cool down before we'll count it again.

Comment: Thanks @Catija can you write that up as an answer so I can close this question out or does it just close after certain amount of days. I'm still new as you can tell by my rep

Comment: [How are the number of views in a question calculated?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36728/how-are-the-number-of-views-in-a-question-calculated). [What is a "closed" or "duplicate" question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-or-duplicate-question)

Comment: Thanks @bobble as i'm still new to meta and stackexchange in general. i was reading and I actually read this question https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36728/how-are-the-number-of-views-in-a-question-calculated the one you posted first. but didn't think it had anything to do with he question I asked. it kinda just merged into the comments with the mod in the previous comments. Thanks for the feedback

Comment: @JcbJoe click the links in my answer to see the search.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Are there no posts that have 0 views or less than 30 views?

There are at the time of this writing

[`views:...30`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=views:...30) 3,998 posts with 30 or less views.

[`views:...6`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=views:...6) 4 posts with with 6 or less views.

[`views:30...30`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=views:30...30) 360 posts with exactly 30 views.

[`views:100000...`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=views:100000...) 35 posts with more than 100k views.

See [How do I search?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/searching)

Comment: For some reason, the results seem inaccurate on Stack Overflow. For example, [`views:..5`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=views%3A..5) returns many questions with a two-figure views number.

Comment: https://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Answer (score 3):

All questions [start with one view](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/259441/what-is-that-1-view-which-automatically-appears-after-submitting-a-question):

> The 1 view you see is that of you, the question owner.
>
> Why? Because you have viewed it.

Searching `views:n` returns all questions with >= n views

[image: search result page for "views:0" showing "views>= 0" as the search option used]

This explains why searching `views:0`:

- doesn't turn up any questions with 0 views (such questions do not exist)
- turns up questions with more than 0 views (the `views:n` operator searches for equal to or greater than views)

To see questions that have less than 30 views, use a range: [`views:..29`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=views%3A..29)